# Regex matching a empty element

Tags: regex

I need help with a regex matching the following.

```
      <xsl:choose>


    </xsl:choose>
```

That is an empty choose element. There might be none or many newlines or space inside.

EDIT: Sorry, was a bit unprecise. I'm trying to fix a broken autogenerated file. I'm opening the file in Visual Stuidio, and are using the Advanced Replace dialog, and using "Regular expression" option.

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Comment: Be more specific, do you want to search only through this one tag, or the whole file and match only the inside of the element. What you have tried so far?

Comment: A regex for which programming language/framework? Many regex engines become a little *weird* when dealing with multiple lines.

Comment: Do I need to add more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Untested (**PHP**):*

```
~<xsl:choose>.*?</xsl:choose>~s
```

Using the `PCRE_DOTALL` [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) and a [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) quantifier.

---

**EDIT**
Sorry, I totally ignored the "empty" part. The [`\s`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand) character class should be used instead of the `.*?` part (thus, leaving the `PCRE_DOTALL` modifier superfluous):

```
~<xsl:choose>\s*</xsl:choose>~
```

This is already in another answer (which will get my upvote).

Comment: @Larsi, No I just ignored important parts of the question :) See @Stephen Chung's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:choose>\s*</xsl:choose>
```

Only white-space between the tags are matched.  If the tag has anything inside, it won't be matched.